# Express wont match url to route when coming from remote server

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm setting up a site that posts to a remote server. The user performs some steps on this remote server and when the user is done. The server issues a get request with a bunch of query parameters to my server.

The thing is that this request never arrives at the controller method it is supposed to.

I have a custom middleware that intercepts all requests and i am doing some logging in there, i can see there every time this request arrives to my server but express doesn't seem to match it to the controller.

However if i go into my browser and do the request from there with the exact same path and query string it works fine.

I thought maybe the remote server was using a proxy so i enabled trust proxy in express but that didn't make any difference.

I have tried changing the route path and that didn't make a difference.

I don't know what code would be helpful since it is pretty standard express code. I have tried putting the route before all the middleware and the request still bypassed the controller and was logged by my logging middleware.

I'm completely baffled, anyone got any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT:
Here is some of the code I'm using. This is not the exact setup I'm trying but I have tried to make it work this way to rule out my routing logic and this example has the exact same problem. I tried putting the app.get above the middleware and the request from the external server still bypassed the app.get and went directly to the middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('path', req.method, req.path, req.query);
 });

app.get('/payments/success', function (req, res) {
    console.log('SUCCESS', req.query);
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Here is the result of the middleware logging a request arriving from the remote server(i removed the variables logged from the request query because it is sensitive information, they are returned just the way they are supposed to):

```
path GET /payment/success { 
    variable: 'variable",
}
```

If anyone needs any more information from the request object i will provide it.

Comment: Could you post the route in question? And some middleware setup?

Comment: You say it "posts" to a remote server and then you say that it works when you put "it in your browser", are you also POSTing from your browser or are you submitting a different type of HTTP request (i.e. POST vs GET)?

Comment: I post to the remote server, the remote server does a GET to my server and so does the browser. I will edit my question with some code samples.